# Reading .mht webpages from server

Tags: html, webserver

We have some `.mht` files which load fine from local files but when loaded from the remote webserver display as junk text.

What can I do to make them work correctly from our webserver?

Comment: What server do you use to serve the files? Apache, nginx, ... ?

Comment: Server is a Parallels Plesk VPS which I believe is CentOS 5.2 which is running Apache.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to enter this in your root's .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# MIME HyperText Markup Language (MHTML) markup
AddType text/html .mhtml .mht .maff .maf
AddType message/rfc822 .mhtml .mht
AddType multipart/related .mhtml .mht .maff .maf
</IfModule>
```

Comment out lines with `#` for those you don't need. Good luck.

Comment: At the moment I have added just: 'AddType message/rfc822 mht' to the Appache httpd.conf.  This seems to partly work.

Comment: define "partly" ;)